# Pulling out XML values from a string in a database column

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq

I have seen various questions on this, but none seem to be working in my problem. I have an Umbraco site set up and it stores its page contents as XML in a database column. An example one is below:

[image]

Sorry for the screen grab and not the actual code, but the editor kept stripping things out.

What I would like to do ideally is either on the page in c#/Linq (have been trying to manipulate is from a string value) or within a SQL query. To be able to pull out the 'url-name', 'nodeName' and 'bodyText' fields.

Many thanks

Comment: I don't suppose there's any way you can change it to an xml column is there?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm afraid not though.

Answer (score 1):

Since the column is not defined as XML in the database, you can pull out the string and parse the text/string as an XML document:

```
// xml would be pulled from the DB
string xml = "<RunwayTextpage nodeName=\"Test page\" urlName=\"test-page\"><bodyText>Body Text</bodyText></RunwayTextpage>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse( xml );

string nodeName = doc.Root.Attribute( "nodeName" ).Value;
string urlName = doc.Root.Attribute( "urlName" ).Value;
string bodyText = doc.Root.Element( "bodyText" ).Value;
```

Another option would be to use string manipulation in the SQL query itself, but that would end up being much less maintainable whereas the above is easily understandable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure how this is going to help though? As you have hard coded a version of the XML in and I am trying to do this dynamically with the content format as show above.

Comment: The XML is not being hard-coded; it's just a sample. Replace the string in the `xml` variable with the string from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use uQuery? Don't really know your purposes, but it has a method called GetNodesByXPath that gets a collection of nodes or node from an XPath expression by querying the in memory xml cache.

It's more wise in terms of performance if your tree is large.